# conditional c++11 threading

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic

I'm trying to understand threading in c++11. Suppose I have an array arr={5,5,5,5,5}, and I want to calculate the value of {5^a^b, 5^a^b, 5^a^b, 5^a^b, 5^a^b} using two threads, with parameter a or b passed to the threads. How do I guarantee that the seconds thread acts on each term only after the first thread has worked on it (the difference between 5^a^b and 5^b^a)?

Thanks.

Comment: google `c++ consumer producer`

Comment: Thanks. Will look into that. I think I'll be able to adapt it to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may share an atomic variable between threads, that would represent the most-left index in array - of element that is not yet processed by first thread.

Increment index in the first thread after operation with `a` and loop in the second thread until index is less than size of an array.

Comment: Would it be inefficient write a loop using atomic variable (for the second thread): 
    
    while(i!=len(arr)){ 
                   if (i<=atomic) {arr[i]=arr[i]^b; ++i}
                   else continue
    }
         
So if I waned to generalize it to multiple passes/threads (5^a^b^c^..), I will have to generate a vector of atomic variables denoting the location of each thread ? Wouldn't a while loop in each thread be inefficient.

Comment: @waqy If you want more than 2 threads in the conveyer, then you may add conditional variables beside atomic counters, and notify a proper thread, when the counter gets incremented. With 2 threads it may be efficient, since there is no too much context switches and modern CPUs have at least 2 cores - the only drawback is a cache synchronization. Generalize your question, and I will generalize my answer :)